# Can't extract module name from some.jar: some.class found in top-level directory (unnamed package not allowed in module)

Tags: java, maven, java-9

We are migrating our software to Java 9. The application that I am working on uses pretty old Java libraries and there is no opportunity to update them.
Here is our `pom.xml` file fragment:

```
<project>
    <repositories>
        ..our private repositories
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <executable>javac10</executable>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>windows</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>windows</family>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.latencybusters.lbm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>UMSJMS</artifactId>
                    <version>5.3.6</version>
                    <classifier>windows</classifier>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

Our current OS is `Windows`. So the problems is with com.latencybusters.lbm library.

`Intellij Idea` doesn't highlight `module-info.java` file as well as any other class. So it was expected that the project would get compiled.
But running `mvn clean compile -X` returns

```
...
[WARNING] Can't extract module name from UMSJMS-5.3.6-windows.jar: lbmmsrc.class found in top-level directory (unnamed package not allowed in module)
...
module-info.java: module not found: UMSJMS
```

What could be the reason of this bug?

Comment: Do you have a `module-info.java` file in your project? If so, you may just have to remove it due to the old non-modularized libraries that your project requires.

Comment: While working with Java9+ , the dependencies in your pom.xml would be treated as an automatic module (if not explicitly exposed as a java module itself). The problem that you see currently is that your library `UMSJMS-5.3.6-windows.jar` has a class named `lbmmsrc.class` which doesn't reside in any of the packages. This is not allowed post Java9 to reside within a module. Hence the change to that library would be able to fix the error you see. (Unless you choose to fall back to Java-8 otherwise.)

Comment: You seem to be upgrading to JDK 9+ and migrating to modules at the same time. You may want to get the upgrade done first, which means leaving everything on the class path, before learning about modules.